# Consulting some diviners tolerated?

Tags: jeremiah

I've asked [this question](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/54611/2705) before with a particular focus on Joseph's life. Now I'd like to broaden the scope by bringing in ​Jeremiah 27:9 (NASB)

> And as for you, do not listen to your prophets, your diviners, your dreamers, your soothsayers, or your sorcerers who talk to you, saying, “You will not serve the king of Babylon.”

Is consulting the other diviners ok?

Comment: These were false prophets.  Deut and 1 John 4 give tests for true prophets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there's a classification in that Jeremiah passage, let's consider the classification of existing roles amongst the people of God - Ephesians 4:11 (NASB)

> And he gave some, apostles; and some, prophets; and some, evangelists; and some, pastors and teachers;

As you can see, there's no divination / sourcerer / ... in there.

The question arises from the assumption that the classification would mean they (prophets,  diviners, dreamers, soothsayers or sorcerers) were all accepted which is not the case in Jeremiah. Instead, this classification serves to show the pagan contamination of the era.

For clarification of the term *divination*, the New Unger's Bible Dictionary states

> Divination, the art of obtaining secret knowledge, especially of the future, is a pagan counterpart of prophecy. Careful comparison of Scripture will reveal that inspirational divination is by demonic power whereas genuine prophecy is by the Spirit of God. The biblical attitude toward divination is by demonic power, whereas genuine prophecy is by the Spirit of God. The biblical attitude toward divination is distinctly hostile (Deut. 18:10-12). The prophet of Jehovah is contrasted with diviners of all sorts and is set forth as the only authorized medium of supernatural revelation. Baalam (Numbers 22-24) was a pagan diviner but rose to the status of a bona-fide prophet of the Lord, although he reverted to paganism. **In Isa. 3:2, Jer. 29:8, Ezek. 22:28 the diviner is classified with the prophet, but this does not mean condonement of divination. It points rather to the apostasy and pagan contamination of the era**. The worship of the true God is basically at variance with divination of every sort. Seeking knowledge of the future from any source other than the God of Israel was an insult to His holy Being and the revelation of Himself and His purpose for men.

As you can see, there's even other passages where such kind of classification is brought up.

---

### Wrap up

> Is consulting the other diviners ok?

Being divination the "pagan counterpart of prophecy", then it's definitely not ok.